# Using keybd_event

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, focus

I have a simple program that does some 'typing' with `keybd_event()`. The problem is that when I focus the program window, any text box where I want to type (e.g. in a browser) becomes unfocused. How do I remedy that?

Comment: It amazes me how many people are just now trying to use the `keybd_event` function, despite the giant warning on the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646304.aspx): **"Note: This function has been superseded. Use [`SendInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310.aspx) instead."**

Comment: Using `SendInput()` is the right thing to do but it isn't really going to help solve the problem.

Comment: No, it doesn't solve the problem. The problem is that UI automation is difficult and fragile. There isn't enough information here to actually solve the problem. A different control in the window is getting the focus, rather than the textbox you want to "type" in.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the hwnd of the textbox you want to type in instead of the window who owns it, this should solve your problems. You might need to enumerate the child windows though, to get the correct resource ids of the textboxes. You should how be using `SendInput`, as you might find you method just not working in certain situations, see all the comments.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent your application which is generating the keyboard events from getting focus, one option would be to create the window of the application with the [WS_EX_NOACTIVATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff700543%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) extended style.